# Are there any data migration tools?

Tags: 10.04, live-usb, persistence

I'm trying to migrate a laptop's HDD to another HDD. I'm trying to find a way to use Ubuntu Live USB with persistence and run tools such as this! I tried disc copy bootable linux distro, didn't work. Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you need all the system settings and partitions or just the data and application settings?

Comment: need everything, upgrading to a bigger hdd. i want it to be bootable and everything.

Comment: I have had success with Mondo Rescue but it was a few years ago and I can't recall the details. It worked well though and I cloned a bunch of servers that are still in production use now with it http://www.mondorescue.org/.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [usb to Sata or IDE adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812232002), a live CD and hook up the old HD to the new computer via the adapter.

Then you should be able to run the following command in a terminal window:

> dd if=[olddisk] of=[newdisk]

Note that you will need to determine what the path is to the old and new disk...

The new one will most likely be /dev/sda... the way to determine that with a GUI is to use 'Disk Utility' and look under the 'device' area.

Depending on the size of your disk this can take quite a while.

You could also give [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or [Partimage](http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page) a try.

[image]